# TableView scroll isn't smooth (Xamarin.iOS)

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have table view with images in cells

But when data is shown in TableView and I scroll it, it not smooth. But all images are downloaded I think.

Here is Code for TableView source

```
public class ExperienceSource : UITableViewSource
{

    //UINavigationController instance, to pass it to constructor
    private UINavigationController primNav { get; set; }
    private UITableView tableView { get; set; }
    List<Experience> TableItems;
    ExperienceTableViewController owner;
    public ExperienceSource(List<Experience> items,ExperienceTableViewController owner, UINavigationController nav)
    {
        TableItems = items;
        this.owner = owner;
        primNav = nav;
    }


    public override nint RowsInSection(UITableView tableview, nint section)
    {

        if (TableItems.Count == 0)
        {


            var noDataLabel = new UILabel
            {
                Text = "No Experiences at your location at this time. Try to change destination",
                TextColor = UIColor.Black,
                TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center,
                LineBreakMode = UILineBreakMode.WordWrap,
                Lines = 0
            };
            tableview.BackgroundView = noDataLabel;
            tableview.SeparatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None;

            return TableItems.Count;
        }
        else
        {

            tableview.SeparatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.SingleLine;
            return TableItems.Count;
        }


    }

    public override async void RowSelected(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        var selectedExperience = await ExperienceMethods.GetSelectedTour(TableItems[indexPath.Row].id);
        if (selectedExperience == "Saved")
        {
        ExperienceDetailViewController ExperienceDetailController = primNav.Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("ExperienceDetailViewController") as ExperienceDetailViewController;
        primNav.PushViewController(ExperienceDetailController, true);

        }
        else
        {
          UIAlertController okAlertController = UIAlertController.Create("", "Cannot select this experience", UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
        okAlertController.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("OK", UIAlertActionStyle.Default, null));
        }
        tableView.DeselectRow(indexPath, true);
    }


    public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        var cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell("cell_id", indexPath) as ExperienceCell;
        Experience item = TableItems[indexPath.Row];
        cell.UpdateCell(item);
        return cell;
    }
```

And I have code for my custom cell in this class

```
 public partial class ExperienceCell : UITableViewCell
{
    public ExperienceCell (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
    }
    internal void UpdateCell(Experience experience)
    {
        UIImage picture;
        try
        {
            var image_url = "https://xplorpal.com/" + experience.cover_image.img_path + "/300x300/" + experience.cover_image.img_file;
            using (var url = new NSUrl(image_url))
            using (var data = NSData.FromUrl(url))
                picture = UIImage.LoadFromData(data);
            ExperienceImage.Image = picture;
        }
        catch { }
        finally
        {
            ExperienceTitle.Text = experience.title;
            ExperiencePrice.Text = "$" + experience.price;
        }
    }
}
```

Where can be my problem and how I can optimize scroll of this TableView?

Thank's for help.

Comment: If you comment out the image code in the UITableViewCell, how is the scrolling experience then?

Comment: All okay and scroll is smooth@SushiHangover

Comment: Two things then,1st.  cache the images locally (i.e. only retrieve them once) and load from the local files and 2nd. You did not state the size of those images, make sure that they are sized properly for their local display resolution/size (i.e. do not load hi-res files when thumbnails or equivalent can be used)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with using NSData.FromUrl method inside a TableViewCell, but handling remote images manually is most of the time a bad idea.

You should consider using a library like SDWebImage, that will handle downloading, caching, and assigning the image to your UIImage for you.

Comment: I tried to use SDWebImage

for example with this code

`var image_url = "https://xplorpal.com/" + experience.cover_image.img_path + "/300x300/" + experience.cover_image.img_file;
                ExperienceImage.Sd_setImageWithURL(new NSUrl(image_url));`

But my images appears only when I scroll tableview. How I can fix this?

Comment: That must be coming from the way / place you call the "UpdateCell" method from. Not related to SDWebImage per say